# it's possible draw a rectangle on Edit control with ES_PASSWORD style?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gdi+, gdi

i'm trying draw a rectangle roundend around of control, i've done something like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindPorc(HWND hwnd, UINT umsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
    {
        // device handle
        HDC Chdc = (HDC)wparam;
        // handle to control
        HWND CHand = (HWND)lparam;

        // new object pen...
        HPEN penx = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(0, 255, 255));


        // apply pen to device handle and back up the original handle
        HGDIOBJ objb = SelectObject(Chdc, penx);

        // auto...
        RECT rectx;
        GetClientRect(CHand, &rectx);  

        // Now draw the rect with round borders...
        RoundRect(Chdc, (rectx.left -2), (rectx.top - 2), (rectx.right + 2), (rectx.bottom + 2), 5, 5);     

        // reset device hand...
        SelectObject(Chdc, objb);

        // Set text color...
        SetTextColor(Chdc, RGB(0, 255, 255));


        // clean up...
        DeleteObject(penx);
        DeleteObject(objb);


        // I should return a brush for the bk, but this don't care now...
        //return;
    }

}


void InitUI()
{
    // just the edit control, isn't need the RegisterClass etc...

        HWND Edit1 = CreateWindowEx
        (
        NULL,
        L"EDIT",
        NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |
        ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE, // Just a demonstration, it should be ES_PASSWORD
        10, 120, 200, 22,
        winx, // parent window HWND...
        (HMENU)TEXTBOX_1, // id
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(winx, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL
        );
}
```

ok, this would look like this:

[image]

but if i change the style on `CreateWindowEx();` to `ES_PASSWORD` the edges disappear, leaving something like this:

[image]

Why do they disappear?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the implementation is wrong in multiple ways:

- `Chdc` is a DC that can draw on the client area of the edit control only, while you want to draw on the parent window's (dialog's) client area.
- `GetClientRect()` always returns (0,0) for the top-left corner, as the rectangle is relative to... the edit control itself.
- `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` may not be the best place to draw the rectangle, you need to make some tests to check when this message is actually called.

If you wish to keep the implementation this way, you should:

- Draw using the parent window's DC, not the edit control's one.
- Instead of `GetClientRect()` call `GetWindowRect()` and then `ScreenToClient()` to make coordinates relative to the parent window's client area.
- Use the `WM_PAINT` message (and the `BeginPaint()`/`EndPaint()` functions) to get a DC for the parent window.

I would consider a different implementation though, create an **Owner-Drawn Static Control**, some few pixels larger than the edit control, placed somehow "around" the edit control (set the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` style to make sure that the edit control stays on top of the static one). Drawing should be carried-out processing the `WM_DRAWITEM` message. I think this implementation is more robust.